# SQLite3 one-line command for exporting table to the .sql file

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails application, I need to export an existing table as .sql file with one-line command ideally

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

**This dumps hole database**

```
db_file = 'db/development.sqlite3'
sh("sqlite3 #{db_file} saraksts > from_file/test.sql")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sqlite3 database.db ".dump table_name"
```

should do it.